# Create Rank column based on multiple column value criterion

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, group-by

Suppose I have the following dataframe

```
   Num1  Num2  Num3
   123    75    43
   123    72    32
   123    72    37
   123    73    41
   456    72    23
   456    75    25
   456    73    21
   456    73    27
```

I need to create another column called `rank`. The expected output would be

```
 Num1  Num2  Num3    rank
   123    75    43    1
   123    72    32    3
   123    72    37    2
   123    73    41    4
   456    72    23    6
   456    75    25    5
   456    73    21    8
   456    73    27    7
```

The logic is: for each `Num1`, check the `Num2`, if it is 75, give them 1st priority, if it is 72, give it 2nd and for 73, it has to be 3rd. For tie breaker case, check `Num3`, priority will be given based on the larger number.

My thought was to `sort` it down, but will work on the `Num3` column not on `Num2`.
I have created

```
df['tcolun'] = df.apply(lambda row: 1 if row['Num2'] == 75 else (2 if row['Num2'] == 72 else 3), axis = 1)
```

But unable to use it properly.

Answer (score 0):

IIUC, craft a mapping dictionary for Num2, then apply your sorting logic and use [`numpy.argsort`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.argsort.html) on the index:

```
import numpy as np

order = [75,72,73]
d = {k:v for v,k in enumerate(order, 1)}
# {75: 1, 72: 2, 73: 3}

df['rank'] = np.argsort(df.assign(Num2=df['Num2'].map(d))
                          .sort_values(by=['Num1', 'Num2', 'Num3'],
                                       ascending=[True, True, False]).index)+1
```

output:

```
   Num1  Num2  Num3  rank
0   123    75    43     1
1   123    72    32     3
2   123    72    37     2
3   123    73    41     4
4   456    72    23     6
5   456    75    25     5
6   456    73    21     8
7   456    73    27     7
```

Alternative with [`groupby`+`ngroup`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.ngroup.html), taking advantage of the fast that `groupby` sorts the groups by default:

```
order = [75,72,73]
d = {k:v for v,k in enumerate(order, 1)}

df.assign(Num2=df['Num2'].map(d),
          Num3=-df['Num3']  # ensure Num3 will sort in reverse order
         ).groupby(['Num1', 'Num2', 'Num3']).ngroup().add(1)
```